# Linux protocol handler to get packets and processes associated to them

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel

Hi Linux networking experts,
I am trying to get a tool to monitor all sockets created by each process, and bandwidth used by each process. I could poll that information from /proc, but I would miss short-lived sockets that are created and destroyed between poll cycles.

The idea was to create a kernel module that registers a protocol handler with the networking subsystem, so that my handler function is called for each packet received. In the handler I wanted to look up the socket associated to the sk_buff, and the process that opened the socket. To get the processes waiting for the socket, I go through the wait queue for the socket and check the tasks in the list. I wrote this:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>
#include <linux/netdevice.h>
#include <linux/skbuff.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <net/datalink.h>
#include <net/inet_hashtables.h>
#include <net/tcp.h>
#include <net/inet_common.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("xxx");
MODULE_AUTHOR("xxxx");

int prot_handler(struct sk_buff *, struct net_device *, struct packet_type *, struct net_device *);

static struct packet_type handler_packet_type __read_mostly = {
    .type = cpu_to_be16(ETH_P_IP),
    .func = prot_handler,
};

int
prot_handler(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev, struct packet_type *pt, struct net_device *orig_dev)
{
    const struct iphdr *iph;
    const struct tcphdr *th;
    struct sock *sk;
    struct socket_wq *wq;
    wait_queue_head_t *q;
    struct task_struct * task;

    //printk(KERN_ALERT "Got sk_buff.\n");
    iph = ip_hdr(skb);
    th = tcp_hdr(skb);
    sk = __inet_lookup_established(dev_net(skb->dev), &tcp_hashinfo,
                       iph->saddr, th->source,
                       iph->daddr, ntohs(th->dest),
                       skb->skb_iif);

    /* __inet_lookup_skb is crashing. It might be because skb_steal_sock? 
     * 
     * __inet_lookup_skb:
     *     skb_steal_sock
     *     __inet_lookup
     *          __inet_lookup_established
     *          __inet_lookup_listener   
     */
    if (!sk)
        return 0;

    //printk(KERN_ALERT "Found active sock.\n");

    // code mimics sock_def_readable

    rcu_read_lock();
    wq = rcu_dereference(sk->sk_wq);
    q = &wq->wait;
    if (wq_has_sleeper(wq)) {
        // code mimics __wake_up_common
        wait_queue_t *curr, *next;
        list_for_each_entry_safe(curr, next, &q->task_list, task_list) {
            task = curr->private;
            if (task && task->pid != 0)
                printk(KERN_ALERT "Got packet for process ID: %d\n", task->pid);
        }
    }
       }
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();

    return 0;
}

static int __init
dev_init(void) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Registering protocol handler with network stack.\n");
    dev_add_pack(&handler_packet_type);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit
dev_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Removing protocol handler.\n");
    dev_remove_pack(&handler_packet_type);
}

module_init(dev_init);
module_exit(dev_exit);
```

When I load this module, and started a ssh session to the system to test it. The  handler gets called when I type something on the remote system, but the PID printed doesn't correlate to what I expect. And the handler doesn't always get called. I think there might be a race condition with ip_rcv.

```
Apr 22 10:20:56 ol71node1 kernel: Got packet for process ID: 13927307
Apr 22 10:20:56 ol71node1 kernel: Got packet for process ID: 13927307
Apr 22 10:20:56 ol71node1 kernel: Got packet for process ID: 13927307
```

Can someone point to how I could do this, even if the use case doesn't make a lot of sense?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a follow-up, I created a similar module but implementing a netfilter hook instead of a protocol handler. I no longer have the race condition issues with __inet_lookup_skb, but the problem is the same. I cannot get the task for the skb. I go through the tasks in the wait queue for the socket, and most times task->pid is 0, or a random number.